# SimpleHTMLDom searching for text inside <td>

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Okay so I'm having a website that has that

```
<tr>
      <td class="first">EURO</td>
      <td class="">1.0</td>
      <td class="">1.2</td>
</tr>
```

using `SimpleHTMLDom` I need to search for "Euro" and get the data of both `<td>` under it

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");

$html = new simple_html_dom();

$html->load_file('currency_rates/default.asp');
?>
```

Sorry I couldn't do anything much here.
I tried searching a lot but I couldn't find what I wanted.

Update:
I tried that code.

```
if ($rows) {

    echo count($rows) . " \$rows found !<br />";

    foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {

        echo "<hr />";

        $columns = $row->find('td');

        // Find succeeded
        if ($rows) {
            $info = array();

            foreach ($columns as $col) {
                    $info = $col->plaintext . " ";
                    echo $info;
                }
        }
        else
            echo " /!\ Find() \$columns failed /!\ ";
    }
}
else
    echo " /!\ Find() \$rows failed /!\ ";
```

Outputs were

```
EURO 1.0996 1.2567 

US DOLLARS 1.2364 1.4088
```

but now I need help saving them into variables (array)

for each different currency

Comment: loop for each row, then for every row, check `td.first`. if value contains the thing you need, get the sibling values of `td.first`.

Comment: Done but I don't know how to store them as variables

Comment: use an associative array